# Tkinter: make a 'disabled' widget look even more 'disabled'

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, state

I have this collection of Listboxes (see image). The 2nd and 3rd Listboxes are disabled by default until the user adds an item to the 1st Listbox and selects it, at which point the two other Listboxes can be edited.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwZlR.png)

The problem i have is that the 'disabled' state of this Listboxes look too much as a 'normal' one, and im worried it might not be intuitive enough for the user that he must work on the first Listbox first.

Is there a way to make the disabled state of a widget look even more disabled?
I was thinking, maybe change the color of the widget to something more darker... but i'm not a graphic designer so i really have no clue.

Is it even possible to change the appearence of disabled widgets in the first place?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be appropriate `listbox.config(highlightthickness = 0, bg = 'grey90')` I don't see much sense in making it look more disabled if there are no items though.

Comment: The thing is, it doesnt look disabled at all...I dont want the user to spend time clicking around and figuring out it's actually disabled..
Your suggestion actually looks decent, it looks disabled at first glance. Thanks!
http://puu.sh/pSjrE/dc17c71738.png